# VaR and CVaR Optimization

Tags: matlab

How to write a Matlab code to make a portfolio optimization with VaR and CVaR?

i imported the data
I extracted the fifth column
I made a matrix fir the prices
I calculated the returns
I made a matrix for the returns.

Can you write me the next codes please